# Pointer to one of the different overload of a function

Tags: scala

I tried the following :

```
def doOperation(op: (Int, Int) => Int) = {
    op(42, 42)
}

doOperation(Int.+)
```

But I got the following error:

```
Error: type mismatch;
 found   : String => String
 required: (Int, Int) => Int
                doOperation(Int.+)
                                ^
```

This is because there is many overload of the `Int::+` operator in scala and the compilator is not clever enough to understand which one to choose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Int.+` is attempting to call a `+` method on the [companion object of `Int`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/?_ga=1.8468725.1939486482.1433104516#scala.Int$). This does not exist, hence the error. You need a function `(Int, Int) => Int`, which you can create anonymously, like this:

```
scala> doOperation((a, b) => a + b)
res9: Int = 84
```

Or for short:

```
scala> doOperation(_ + _)
res10: Int = 84
```

Answer (score 1):

First, Int.+ is one argument method, so you should try this instead:

```
def doOperation(op: (Int) => Int) = {
    op(42)
}

doOperation(Int.+)
```

to realize that it doesn't work neither, because, as @m-z already explained, `Int.+` is an attempt to reference a method of a companion object `Int`, which has only `box`, `unbox` methods and a couple of implicit conversions.
You could however try to operate on some instance of Int, like that:

```
def doOperation(op: (Int) => Int) = {
    op(42)
}
val i = 7
doOperation(i.+)
```

This works as expected.

Sidenote. This won't work:

```
def doOperation(op: (Int) => Int) = {
    op(42)
}
val i = 7
val iplus = i.+
doOperation(i.+)
```

because `+` is an overloaded method and compiler doesn't know which one to store in `iplus` variable.